# How can I apply animation on Gallery : Animated Gallery Android

Tags: android-animation, android

I am looking for widget which looks something like image shown bellow

[image]

I am not having any idea how to achieve this kind of image transformation, can anyone guide me from where I need to start or which is the android class I need to modify on order to have this, does anyone have any sample code which I can refer?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieved this by using the StackView feature. Check out below links,Hope this link help for you.

1) [android-stackview](http://www.thaicreate.com/mobile/android-stackview.html)

2) [example](http://docs.huihoo.com/android/3.0/resources/samples/StackWidget/src/com/example/android/stackwidget/index.html)

3) [stacked card view](http://www.broculos.net/2011/12/android-101-how-to-create-stackview.html#.UdPO9KrS0UQ)